# How to display videos in homepage from database in django

Tags: python, django, video, filefield

I've made a portfolio website with django and bootstrap framework. Now i'm trying to display multiple videos in my homepage. So through admin panel i uploaded 3 videos and in template used video tag. In model FileField for upload and also summary for video description. After setup and runserver my website homepage is showing just video description and video player and controls. There is no such videos or thumbnails to play. Please help me on that matter.
Thanks in Advance.

Model view and template code images are as follows-

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please add the code to your question - text, rather than image.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by changing Videos=Video.objects.all() & Then inside the template by writing {{ video.video.url }} That's it!